# What happened to RichTextBoxOverflow in Silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Found bunch of articles with code (assuming it was ran at some point of time) using RichTextBox and RichTextBoxOverflow (supposedly introduced in Silverlight 5)..

I cant find **RichTextBoxOverflow** in the Silverlight controls.

Had it been cut out on release? Or moved to some obscure dll ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RichTextBoxOverflow was introduced in Silverlight 5 beta, but it was cut from Silverlight 5 final release.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it was released at all by that name (see [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/1a8aefdb-0b0a-4250-8a6a-3d3b50c81fa6/where-richtextboxoverflow-?forum=silverlightgen)). But there's [RichTextBlockOverflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh373578%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) though.

Comment: yeah I saw that.. but the 'answer' was : `From research, there is not a RichTextBoxOverFlow control but a RichTextBlockOverFlow control.`... So I wanted to hear from someone who actually knows.. Not from research